# Show on 'checked'

Tags: jquery

What's wrong with this example:

```js
$('label#formSecondPhone:first-child').change(function() {
    var id = $('#formSecondPhoneField');
    $(this).attr('checked') ? $(id).show() : $(id).hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label id="formSecondPhone"><input type="checkbox" name="secondContact" value="1"> Phone</label> 
<label id="formSecondPhoneField" class="form-item">Enter your number: <input type="number" name="secondPhone"></label>
```

The formSecondPhoneField is not showing / hiding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Change you selector of checkbox
2. Use .is(":checked") to check for check status of checkbox

```js
$(':checkbox[name=secondContact]').change(function() {
  var id = $('#formSecondPhoneField');
  
  console.log($(this).is(':checked'))
  $(this).is(':checked') ? $(id).show() : $(id).hide();
}).change();
```

```css
#formSecondPhoneField {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label id="formSecondPhone"><input type="checkbox" name="secondContact" value="1"> Phone</label>
<label id="formSecondPhoneField" class="form-item">Enter your number: <input type="number" name="secondPhone"></label>
```